# In Facebook, is it possible to delete multiple friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I'm looking for a way to delete multiple friends. I created my Facebook account years ago, when I was still in high school, and it was a thing to basically add everybody in the school. Now, 5 years later, I’ve got over 3000 friends. I want to remove all these people and bring my list down to two digits. Creating a whole new account seems redundant and counter-productive.

If there is no way to do this, could somebody kindly point me in the right direction to creating said option myself? I have HTML5 and CSS experience. My JavaScript isn't the best but, I learn more and more everyday.

Comment: I have done some research on my question. It seems there were options that allowed me to do this via chrome extensions. But they are all outdated to 2012.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this via Facebook desktop. Additionally using browser extensions might trigger Facebook to think something is suspiciously happening to your account.

*In theory*, you will need to use the API (which is outside of the scope of this site) with a whitelisted application that can execute HTTP DELETE on `/me/friends` while staying under the rate limit.